# Deserializing a class inside another class from json

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
   "userName" : "player3322",
   "userLevel" : 23,
   "userInventory" : {
       "primaryHand" : "3493",
       "secondaryHand" : "none"
   }
}
```

to deserialize this I've made two classes like this:

```
public class PlayerData{
    public string userName;
    public int userLevel;
    public UserInventoryData userInventory;
}

public class UserInventoryData {
    public string primaryHand,secondaryHand;
}
```

But for some reason after deserializing it using JsonUtility.FromJson , userInventory inside the playerData class stays null and I can't access to the content inside userInventory.
How can I deserialize all of the my JSON? thanks

Comment: As far as I can see the json seems incorrect. After "none" there should not be a ,

Comment: Youre right , but it's not the real JSON. I wrote it manually for the example.

Comment: Have you added `[Serializable]` to both PlayerData and UserInventoryData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what deserializer you are using, but with `Newtonsoft.Json`, this is working fine.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string str = "{'userName' : 'player3322','userLevel' : 23,'userInventory' : {'primaryHand' : '3493','secondaryHand' : 'none',}}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerData>(str);

Console.WriteLine(obj);

Console.WriteLine(obj.userInventory.primaryHand);

public class PlayerData{
    public string userName;
    public int userLevel;
    public UserInventoryData userInventory;
}

public class UserInventoryData {
    public string primaryHand,secondaryHand;
}
```

Comment: I've been using JsonUtility . It's Unity's built-in light-weight json de/serializer. Btw thanks for the answer, I'll check it out

Comment: Perhaps it requires other objects to be properties instead of variables, e.g. `public UserInventoryData userInventory { get; set; }`.

Comment: Actually Using Newtonsoft json deserializer solved my problem. thank you.